# Ethernet Connection Is Not Working

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I'm working on Ubutntu 18.04.3 LTS, Wi-Fi is working normally while Ethernet not available.

[image]

I tried this solution:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

It worked for two days, I mean the problem was soved, and I was able to connect through ethernet cable, but after that the problem re-appear. I tried the commends again, but this time it didn't worked.
Even I tried most of the appearing solution available but nothing solves it.
This command: 
`ip link show`
gives this output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:4b:f5:28:25:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Please any different solutions for this problem, or detecting for the case I have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands solve the problem finally,

```
sudo modprobe -r r8169
sudo modprobe r8169
```